# how to make multiple select checkbox with ajax and no button submit

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, checkbox

Python 3.9 Django 3.2
I have categories and product , and through a simple form in the template I choose 1 or 2-3 checkboxes and I get the result.
How to do it now via ajax and without button 'submit'.

I select several product categories and each click on the checkbox is ajax
and the next click on the checkbox adds the parameter to the request.

it is similar to how you select several parameters in online stores. You have selected 2 parameters and received a filtered list of products

I suppose that you need to intercept the sending, store one request in the cache and add a new one to this request

```
              <form  method="post" id="category-box">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name='category' value="{{c.name}}" >
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="{{c.name}}"><a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a></label>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have an `onChange` on the `form` element which triggers when any input within the form has been changed. When the form changes, you send AJAX request with updated params and load new data.

This might be hurtful for performance though, clicking multiple checkboxes in short period of time would trigger a request for each click which is unnecessary. That can be handled with a slight delay before sending the request and a check if the form has changed subsequently.

Comment: The delay is an excellent idea. It takes time for the user to click each checkbox, so do not submit a request immediately. Each onChange resets the delay. Finally the user pauses long enough that the AJAX request is submitted. So many shopping sites should implement this.

Comment: Thank you! I completely agree, submit buttons are overrated :D The same delay principle also works well when you implement search input and trigger requests on keyup event. If you give it like 0.5-1 second delay it's not that drastic but it allows user to write (or click) options they want and only after the delay expires it triggers the request with final values.

Comment: @thegman1001 I understand this, and so I did. But this is not what I need. Now it works like this - every time a checkbox is selected, the old (previous) filter is reset and I get a new one. And I need to add a new filter to the previous filter and all this through ajax and without the send button

Comment: @Ivan not sure how the rest of your code looks like but you'll have to handle it in a way to support extending previous values with newly selected ones. I'm assuming you're facing the problem because every checkbox in your for loop has the same name. When a checkbox is selected you should push that value to an array or remove it from the array when it's deselected.